# IOS Creating list of Dictionaries in plist

Tags: ios, plist

I am having trouble to write new dictionaries in my plist file where I want to save data each time the user fill a form.
The code I am using right now only overwrite the data and doesn´t save the previous dictionary as wanted.

here the code :

```
//////////// Save data into plist /////////////////
// get paths from root direcory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
// get documents path
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
// get the path to our Data/plist file
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

// set the variables to the values in the text fields
self.titlestring = titleexperiencia.text;
self.descriptionstring = descriptionexperiencia.text;
self.coordinadastring = [self deviceLocation];

// create dictionary with values in UITextFields
NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: titlestring, descriptionstring,coordinadastring, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Title", @"Description", @"Coordinate", nil]];

NSString *error = nil;
// create NSData from dictionary
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];

// check is plistData exists
if(plistData) 
{
    // write plistData to our Data.plist file
    [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"Saved in Data Plist");

}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"Error in saveData: %@", error);
    [error release];
}
```

I also tried to use AddObject: instead of writeToFile: but that make the App crash.

Comment: where are you getting the error from? Why are you releasing the error local variable if you haven't retained it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the crash is probably being caused because you're overreleasing the error variable.

Answer (score 0):

Read the contents of the plistPath:
    NSMutableData *myData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
And change this:

```
// create NSData from dictionary
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];
```

to:

```
// create NSData from dictionary
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];  
[myData appdendData:plistData];
```

and finally write myData to file.

Hope that helps!